# For iOS 6, how do I load data on a background thread and then update the UI?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

There are lots of ways to do this, but what is the current, modern, correct way for IOS 6 apps?

Here's what I'm doing now:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    __weak MyViewController *weakSelf = self;

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT,
                                         (unsigned long)NULL), ^(void) {
        // Do work that will take a long time
        // Store data in member variables, etc.

        // Update the UI 
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [weakSelf.myTableView reloadData];
        });
    }
}
```

With ARC, I don't think the __weak reference is necessary, but I'm not 100% sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're doing is completely the right way to go! The weak reference is needed when you use blocks and is totally ARC. Before ARC, "weak" didn't exist yet.

Comment: THe use of `weak` is not need in this case. You only need to create the "weak self" if you have the risk of a retain cycle between `self` and the block. That isn't an issue in this code.