# Loading data from cell to detailView always show the last data

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitabbarcontroller

I have UITableView with some data from backend, I have everything in table,3 UILable and I will get that information from backend and I can show them in table row, when I click on row I want to have the same label in my detail view, but now, I have just one information in all my detail view, same information, just load the last row for all detailView,

would you please help me in this implementation,
Thanks in advance!

cellForRowAtIndexPath method

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath
*)indexPath

{

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"BooksCell";
BooksCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell =[ [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"BooksCell" owner:nil options:nil]   
lastObject];
}

_books = [server get_tests:10 offset:0 sort_by:0 search_for:@""];
_t = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%@ ", [_books objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

NSString *testdata = _t;

_components = [testdata componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
NSLog(@"_components:  %@",_components);
for (NSString *aComponent in _components) {
    if ([aComponent hasPrefix:@"title"]) {
        _subComponents = [aComponent componentsSeparatedByString:@":"];
        _titleString = [_subComponents[1] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet
 characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"\""]];


    }if ([aComponent hasPrefix:@"authors"]){
        _subComponents = [aComponent componentsSeparatedByString:@":"];
        _writerString = [_subComponents[1] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet
 characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"\""]];


    }if ([aComponent hasPrefix:@"name"]){
        _subComponents = [aComponent componentsSeparatedByString:@":"];
        _publisherString = [_subComponents[1] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:
[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"\""]];



        break;
    }
}



cell.bookTitle.text = _titleString;
cell.writer.text = _writerString;
cell.publisher.text = _publisherString;

return cell;
}
```

didSelectRowAtIndexPath method

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath 
*)indexPath
{
[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];


BooksDetailView *c = [[BooksDetailView alloc] init];
[self.booksTable addSubview:c.view];

c.bDetailTitle.text = _titleString;
c.bDetailWriter.text = _writerString;
c.bDetailPublisher.text = _publisherString;


}
```

Comment: isn't this the same question you asked before? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19460443/objective-c-table-cell-just-returns-last-information-of-matching-data

Comment: @GabrielePetronella thanks for reply, no that one was for my cells and works fine, but this one is for detail view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`_titleString`, `_writerString` and `_publisherString` seem to be *instance* variables
of the table view controller, and these are overwritten in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`
each time a cell is displayed.

You have to use the `indexPath` in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` to get the correct element
of your data source.

Note also that fetching all elements from the server in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`
is very ineffective, because this method is called frequently.

You should fetch the data once (e.g. in `viewDidLoad`) and assign
the fetched array to an instance variable or property of the view controller.
Then you can access the elements from the array in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and in 
`didSelectRowAtIndexPath`.

---

Add a property

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *books;
```

to the view controller. Fetch the data in viewDidLoad:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.books = [server get_tests:10 offset:0 sort_by:0 search_for:@""];
    // ... other stuff ...
}
```

In cellForRowAtIndexPath you just get the element from the array.
Also, instead of all that string manipulation, you should use the model class
and property accessors generated by the Thrift API.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath
                                                                               *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"BooksCell";
    BooksCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell =[[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"BooksCell" owner:nil options:nil] lastObject];
    }

    YourModelClass *book = self.books[indexPath.row];
    cell.bookTitle.text = book.title;
    // ...

    return cell;
}
```

And similarly in didSelectRowAtIndexPath:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath 
*)indexPath
{
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    BooksDetailView *c = [[BooksDetailView alloc] init];
    [self.booksTable addSubview:c.view]; // WHY THAT?

    YourModelClass *book = self.books[indexPath.row];
    c.bDetailTitle.text = book.title;
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, would you please let me know how, I used something like this but it never works c.booksDetail = self.data[indexPath.row]; and also would you please give me an example for fetched array in my viewDidLoad instead on table

Comment: Thanks you so much I will check it, I have one more question to you I post it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19550593/using-coredata-for-loading-information-in-uitableview maybe it helps other person , would you please check it

Comment: for this information that you gave me what is YourModelClass, since I'm not using core Data?

Comment: @AliMohamad: As I understand it from the [documentation](http://wiki.apache.org/thrift/ThriftUsageObjectiveC), Thrift generates a Objective-C class for the structs in the IDL file (like `Testadata` in your previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19501116/show-specific-data-from-nsmutablestring). That is what I mean with "YourModelClass".

Comment: I have one more question, I connect to the server in my ViewDidLoad ,I know that it's wrong, where is the best way to put my data for connecting to the backend? I appreciate your help

Comment: @AliMohamad: The best way is to load the data in a *background thread*  so that the UI is not blocked, and reload the table view when the data has arrived. But that would be a new question!

Comment: Thanks :)) yes do you have sample or any hints for me

Comment: I used this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13863812/for-ios-6-how-do-i-load-data-on-a-background-thread-and-then-update-the-ui but I have delay to  load my table

Comment: @AliMohamad: This is a new and separate problem, so I would suggest that you post a new question if necessary. Then more people read it and can help. - If my answer solved the problem in *this* question then it would be nice if you "accept" it.

Comment: sure,sorry, I added new question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19553465/objective-c-having-delay-to-load-information-in-table, thanks a lot for your helps